# PHP PECL Trader Extension trader_cdl3linestrike($open, $high, $low, $close)

Tags: php, algorithmic-trading, pecl

Unfortunately, the documentation for the Trader Extension is very marginal: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trader-cdl3linestrike.php

I would expect a true or false answer, but I don't care.

But it is absolutely impossible for me to feed this function with data which does not return false. Here is the one example, which is definitely a 3 line strike. Still, the answer is only a false.

[image]

```
$open = array(13, 18, 22, 24);
$high = array(18, 22, 25, 25);
$low = array(12, 17, 21, 10);
$close = array(13, 18, 22, 11);

$result = trader_cdl3linestrike($open, $high, $low, $close);

var_dump($result);

// Result:
// bool(false)
```

Do you have any idea where my thought error is? What do I need to throw into this function to make it recognize a 3 line strike as such?

Many thanks and greetings from Munich!

Alex